# Beam Sword equipment for SSB4?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I have over 1000 pieces of custom equipment, yet none of them give me a beam sword in hand at the start of the match. I've seen a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kerp9FHkkzU) where someone has a beam sword in trophy rush so I know it's out there.

On the 3DS there's a challenge that awards a beam sword agility badge (40 combo in training mode). How can I get one on Wii U?

Comment: None of the Wii U challenges award Beam Sword equipment, so if there's any way of getting one without randomness, it'll be from the "for reward" of one of the events. Whether such exists I don't currently know, because I have yet to do all said events.

Comment: I suddenly have one. Don't know how, will try to backtrack but I'm not sure how.

Comment: As Toomai said, _could possibly_ just be obtainable through Classic, Smash Tour, or even Trophy Rush. Good luck. **You might need it**.

Comment: Any updates on this? It seems to be rare enough to only exist within a few modes, but so far no one has reported a specific mode it was obtained in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since asking this question I've spent a lot more time playing SSB4, and eventually the beam sword equipment started dropping. It's a matter of time, I guess.

The first one was just there, missed the drop. The second was in All-Star, the third in Crazy Orders.

Comment: Do you recall what difficulty you were playing All-Star at? Or what level you were at in Crazy Orders?

Comment: All Star was probably normal. Crazy orders could have been anywhere between 5 and 30.

Comment: What's the name of the equipment that gives beam sword? Would help when sorting equipment alphabetically.